# Tell my injected DLL to load a library from another place in C++?

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, code-injection

Ok, I hope the title explains it well enough...

Basically, I've created a DLL in which I'm running LUA code. The DLL is injected into another EXE in another folder. Here's my issue.

The DLL requires lua52.dll to run, so that means I have to place lua52.dll inside the folder with the exe I'm injecting INTO to make my program run. How can I make it so that I can place the lua52.dll inside MY folder (where my injected dll is) and be ran from there.

C:\Location1 (Holds my dll and the program that injects it)

C:\Location2 (Holds the exe I'm injecting into, but also HAS to hold lua52.dll)

I want location1 to be able to hold lua52.dll

BTW I know how to find the location of my DLL, I just dont know how to force my DLL to load lua52.dll from a specific place.

Answer (score 0):

I think [LoadLibrary or LoadLibraryEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179(v=vs.85).aspx) should suffice for that purpose. You pass it the path to your module and it will load it into your process. Check out the MSDN article on [run-time dynamic linking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a detailed explanation. Their example usage can be found somewhere there...but for short it looks like:

```
typedef int (__cdecl *Add)(int, int); // The Method I care about
...
hLibrary = LoadLibrary(TEXT("lua52.dll")); 
AddMethod = (Add) GetProcAddress(hLibrary, "Add"); // Get Location of method
int value = (AddMethod) (1, 2); // Call the method
...
fFreeResult = FreeLibrary(hLibrary);
```

Of course, that is with error checks removed. You will need to null-checks to verify you loaded it all correctly.